# Check and open downloaded file in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I must check downloaded PDF and open it using *Selenium*. For that, I am using [Robot](https://stqatools.com/selenium-robot-class/) class. This is not the permanent or we can say general solution of this.

Question : Can anyone please help and provide more reliable solution for the same ?

Please find below code:

```java
public boolean CommonEvents(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException { 

    try {   

        Thread.sleep(2000);     
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.mouseMove(100, 700);
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

        Thread.sleep(10000);

    } catch(Exception e) {

         BaseTest.reportPass(driver, null, "Should click on PDF to open", "Failed to click on PDF to open");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you really need to open every downloaded PDF then I would simply add this line to your preferences (e.g. for Firefox):

```
ffprofile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "application/pdf");
```

Then it will automatically open the downloaded file after finishing the download.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar to this if you have a fixed directory where you are saving the downloaded pdf files .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  try {

    File pdfFile = new File("c:\\Hello.pdf");
    if (pdfFile.exists()) {

        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(pdfFile);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Awt Desktop is not supported.");
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println("File doesn't exists.");
    }

    System.out.println("File opened.");

  } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }

}
```

Reference : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html

Answer (score 0):

We use below logic:

1. First set preference for a download location, so that the file will be downloaded to your desired location.

   chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
2. Set Preference so that it won't ask the pop to download.

   chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
3. As @Mudit_ has answered check for the *.pdf with regex pattern, if you want to make it dynamic.